# Is there a way to call the most subclass implementation of a method?

Tags: c#, oop, polymorphism

In my game i'm making in unity i have an abstract superclass `SpaceshipController` and it contains an implemented method `protected void updateSpaceshipMovement()`. For every spaceship there is a subclass and in some of them the method is overriden (`protected new void updatePlayerMovement()`). The method when called in the superclass uses the implementation of `SpaceshipController` and i wanted to know if theres a way to call the implementation in the subclasses when the method is called in the superclasses code.

Comment: Why are you using `new` instead of making the base method `virtual` and overriding in the subclass?

Comment: @BabakNaffas because i don't completely undestrood the virtual identifier.

Comment: `virtual` in difference to `abstract` means: The method already has an implementation in the parent class but can be overwritten anyway or extended using `base.method`

Comment: You've said both "it is overridden" and "it is new".  But "overridden" and "new" are opposites.  If you don't understand that fact, then stop programming, understand that fact, and then start over with a correct understanding.

Comment: Imagine that every virtual method declares a "slot", and every override puts a different method in that slot, and every "new" makes a new slot.  Now do you see why "override" and "new" are opposites?  "override" means "change the value of this slot", and "new" means "leave the old slot unchanged and make a new slot".  You need to understand how this works if you are going to be successful programming in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question:

> No, not the way you implemented this.

How should the base class know that there is somewhere an inherited class which has a method that overwrites its method and should be called instead?

---

You have to properly inherit (`override`) the method using the `virtual` keyword. For showing the difference I also added an `abstract` method.

```
public abstract class SpaceshipController 
{
    // already has an implementation but might be extended or overruled
    protected virtual void updateSpaceshipMovement()
    {
        // do something general
    }

    // does not have an implementation -> HAS to be implemented by subclass
    protected abstract void Something();
}
```

If there are no `abstract` methods you might not even have to make the base class `abstract` at all.

Now in the subclass `override` the `virtual` method. (And implement the `abstract` ones.)

```
public class ExampleController : SpaceshipController 
{
    // I don't have to implement updateSpaceshipMovement
    // but I want to extend or overwrite it
    protected override void updateSpaceshipMovement()
    {
        // optional: anyway execute base code
        base.updateSpaceshipMovement();

        // do other stuff
    }

    // I have to implement this
    protected override void Something()
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

- [**`virtual`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual) means:
  The method already has an implementation in the base class but can be overwritten anyway or extended using `base.method()`
- [**`abstract`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract) means:
  There is no implementation in the base class => has to be implemented by the subclass.

---

In the case that all subclasses should have their own implementation and not use `base.updateSpaceshipMovement` at all maybe an [interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface) might even be better:

```
public interface ISpaceshipController
{
    void updateSpaceshipMovement();
}
```

An `interface` could be kind of explained as an `abstract class` which contains **only** `abstract` methods, **BUT** one class later can implement **multiple** interfaces which makes it a very mighty tool.

Implement it e.g. like

```
public class ExampleController : MonoBehaviour, ISpaceshipController
{
    // I have to implement this to fulfill the interface implementation
    public void updateSpaceshipMovement()
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case `spaceshipController` has a lot of already implemented methods so it can't be an interface, but thankls for your detailed answer. It explained it very well.

Comment: I recommend cleaning up your definitions of `virtual` and `abstract`.  As written, it is not immediately obvious whether "The method already has an implementation in the parent class but can be overwritten anyway or extended using base.method" is describing a virtual modifier on a base class or a parent class.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking about is polymorphism. In your scenario, you can achieve this by providing a default implementation in your abstract class (as a virtual method) and them allowing each sub-class to provide their own implementation by overriding the method.

In `SpaceshipController`, change  `protected void updateSpaceshipMovement()` to `protected virtual void updateSpaceshipMovement()`. This is telling the compiler to use this default implementation for SpaceshipController and any subclasses.

In your subclass, change `protected new void updatePlayerMovement()` to `protected override void updatePlayerMovement()`. This is telling the compiler to use this modified implementation for this particular class.

```
protected override void updatePlayerMovement(){
  base.updatePlayerMovement(); //you can also call the parent implementation first if you so choose.
  //now perform the actions specific to this sub class.

}
```

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/abstract-and-sealed-classes-and-class-members.
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/polymorphism